# how to draw circles using html and css like this?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to draw this circle here's my code so far.

```html
 <div class="circle">
      <svg height="360" width="380">
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="rgb(177,236,250"></circle>
           <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="90"  fill="rgb(177,236,250)" ></circle>
           <circle cx="290" cy="220" r="160"  fill="rgb(177,236,250)"></circle>
           <circle cx="80" cy="220" r="80"  fill="rgb(177,236,250)"></circle>
      </svg>
</div>
```

but it looks so different.

[image: Circles with transparency]

Comment: What do you mean it looks different? You give them different properties

Comment: Make your requirements clear in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **rgba** instead of **RGB** to set transparency:

```html
<div class="circle">
      <svg height="360" width="380">
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
           <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="90"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)" ></circle>
           <circle cx="290" cy="220" r="160"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
           <circle cx="80" cy="220" r="80"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
     </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add transparency to your colors, replace `fill="rgb(177,236,250)"` with `fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"`. The **0.5** is the alpha value of your color, the value go from **0** (fully transparent) to **1** (opaque).

```html
 <div class="circle">
    <svg height="360" width="380">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="90"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)" ></circle>
        <circle cx="290" cy="220" r="160"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
        <circle cx="80" cy="220" r="80"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` for transparent colors. Also, you can use `"position:relative;z-index:(order)"` to determine which one will appear at the top.

```html
 <div class="circle">
            <svg height="360" width="380">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,.8)" style="position:relative;z-index:1"></circle>
                <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="90"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,.5)" style="position:relative;z-index:4"></circle>
                <circle cx="290" cy="220" r="160"  fill="rgba(177,236,250,.4)" style="position:relative;z-index:3"></circle>
                <circle cx="80" cy="220" r="80"  fill="rgb(177,236,250,.7)" style="position:relative;z-index:2"></circle>
            </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div class="circle">
            <svg height="360" width="380">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"  fill="rgb(177,236,250,0.5"></circle>
                <circle cx="100" cy="120" r="90"  fill="rgb(177,236,250,0.7)" ></circle>
                <circle cx="290" cy="220" r="160"  fill="rgb(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
                <circle cx="80" cy="220" r="80"  fill="rgb(177,236,250,0.5)"></circle>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

Sea this one.

Comment: Please let me know where I did wrong. why I had a downvote.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.